# Solutions to $x^p \equiv 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have
\begin{align*}
 p = 2p_1+1 && p_1 = 2p_2+1 \\
    q = 2q_1+1 && q_1 = 2q_2+1
\end{align*}
where $p,q, p_1, q_1, p_2$ and $q_2$ are distinct primes.
I am now trying to find the number of solutions for the congruence
$$x^{p_2} \equiv 1 \pmod{4p_1q_1}$$
I know that the answer is supposed to be $p_2$ but I cannot figure out why that is. 
I can assume that $p_1, q_1$ and $4$ are pairwise relatively prime, so I can break it up into
\begin{align*}
x^{p_2} &\equiv 1 \pmod{4}\\
x^{p_2} &\equiv 1 \pmod{p_1}\\
x^{p_2} &\equiv 1 \pmod{q_1}
\end{align*}
but I am stuck from here. Any hints?

Comment: When you rewrite your equation in terms of congruences in $4,p_1,q_1$, it should be clear that the first congruence gives you one solution. The second one gives you $p_2$ solutions(modulo $p_1$) which can be shown with Fermat's little theorem. The last one gives you one solution (modulo $q_2$) so you get $p_2$ solutions altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $x^{p_2} \equiv1(\textrm{mod}\hspace{3pt}4)$. This tell me $x$ is odd so, $x\equiv \pm 1(\textrm{mod}\hspace{3pt}4)$. But $(-1)^{p_2}\equiv -1(\textrm{mod}\hspace{3pt}4)$ as $p_2$ is odd.

So, $x\equiv 1 (\textrm{mod}\hspace{3pt}4)$

2. $x^{p_2}\equiv 1(\textrm{mod}\hspace{3pt}p_1)$

Fermat's little theorem tells us that $x^{p_1-1}\equiv x^{2p_2}\equiv 1(\textrm{mod}\hspace{3pt}p_1)$. Since $p_1$ is a prime, $a^2\equiv 1(\textrm{mod}\hspace{3pt}p_1)$ tell us $a\equiv \pm 1 (\textrm{mod}\hspace{3pt}p_1)$. Now of the $p_1-1$ classes that are not identical to $0$, exactly half of them will satisfy $x^{p_2}\equiv -1(\textrm{mod}\hspace{3pt}p_1)$ and exactly half of them will satisfy $x^{p_2}\equiv 1(\textrm{mod}\hspace{3pt}p_1)$.

(There are several ways of seeing this. Either consider the fact that there is a primitive root for modulo primes or looking at the bijection $a\mapsto -a$ where $a$ is an element whose $p_2$-th power is $1$.)

So in particular, there are $\frac{p_1-1}{2}=p_2$ distinct solutions modulo $p_2$.

3. $x^{p_2}\equiv 1(\textrm{mod}\hspace{3pt}q_1)$.

Fermat tells me $x^{2q_2}\equiv 1 (\textrm{mod}\hspace{3pt}q_1)$. Unless $p_2=2$, we have that $2q_2$ and $p_2$ are coprime as $q_2$ and $p_2$ are distinct primes. So, in particular, $x^{p_2}\equiv 1 (\textrm{mod}\hspace{3pt}q_1)$ immediately tells me $x\equiv 1(\textrm{mod}\hspace{3pt}q_1)$.

So finally, $1\times p_2\times 1=p_2$ is the number of solutions.

Comment: good answer, you beat me to it. but you miss an important part what about the the other solution when $x^{p_2} = -1 \mod 4 $ and $x^{p_2} = -1 \mod p_1$ which adds another $p_2$ solutions **unless you prove that they are the same as the previous $p_2$ solutions**.

Comment: @Ahmad I am not sure what you mean unless the subscripts are not what they are supposed to be. We are using Chinese remainder theorem so we know as a fact that $x^p_2\equiv 1(\textrm{mod}\hspace{3pt} 4)$ and similarly for $p_2$.

Comment: Assume $x^{p_2} = 1 \mod 4$ and $x^{p_2} = 1 \mod p_1$ then $(-x)^{p_2} = -1 \mod 4 $ and $(-x)^{p_2} = -1 \mod p_1$ so they are both valid solutions to $x^{p_2} = 1 \mod 4 p_1$ , but the problem with your answer as with the one i was working on is the i did not deal with the other valid solutions (in proving that they are actually equal to the first $p_2$ solutions )

Comment: In your first line, did you meant to say $(-1)^{p_2} \equiv -1 \pmod{4}$ as $p_2$ is odd? If not, how does it follow from $p_1$ being odd?

Comment: Thanks, @Nasenhaar. Edit has been made.

Comment: @Ahmad, I am sorry but I still cannot follow you. I guess what you did was assume $a\equiv -1(\textrm{mod}\hspace{3pt} n)$ and $a\equiv -1(\textrm{mod}\hspace{3pt} m)$ implies, $a\equiv(-1)(-1)\equiv 1 (\textrm{mod}\hspace{3pt} mn)$. Going back to the original definitions of modulo arithmetic, if $4p_1$ divides $x^{p_2}-1$ implies that $4$ divides $x^{p_2}-1$ and similarly, $p_1$ divides $x^{p_2}-1$.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer! Would you mind helping me out again with the 3rd case? How does $x^{p_2} \equiv 1 \pmod{p_1}$ immediately tell you that $x \equiv 1 \pmod{q_1}$?

Comment: By Fermat, $x^{q_1-1}\equiv 1(\textrm{mod}\hspace{3pt} q_2)$. We also know $x^{p_2}\equiv 1(\textrm{mod}\hspace{3pt} p_2)$. By Bezout's identity(or if you prefer by using Euclid's algorithm), we know there are integers $a,b$ such that $a(q_2-1)+b(p_1)=1$. This is because $q_2-1=2q_1$ and $p_1$ are coprime. So $x^{a(q_2-1)+b(p_1)}\equiv 1(\textrm{mod}\hspace{3pt} q_2)$.